# Canvas rectangle (progress bar) with rounded ends - Issue with low values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a rectangle that has a width dependant on a percentage, I got it perfectly working until I tested something with 0%.

I wanted it to disappear at 0% but it appears as I opted for rounded corners, that there is a minimum width. The same issue is apparent with lower percentage numbers, and from what I can gather, it pushes the object the opposite way if the percentage is lower than 6%, at that point the rectangle becomes a circle and can not get any smaller. Is there a workaround for this? I have my heart set on it looking the way it does, currently, just need this issue to be fixed.

```js
const canvas = $("#progressBar");
const ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

// rectWidth = 630 * percent / 100 (in this case 100%)
const rectX = 60;
const rectY = 10;
const rectWidth = 630 * 100 / 100;
const rectHeight = 38;
const cornerRadius = 37;

ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = cornerRadius;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF1700';
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';

ctx.strokeRect(rectX + (cornerRadius / 2), rectY + (cornerRadius / 2), rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
ctx.fillRect(rectX + (cornerRadius / 2), rectY + (cornerRadius / 2), rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight - cornerRadius);

// rectWidth = 630 * percent / 100 (in this case 0%)
const rectX2 = 60;
const rectY2 = 60;
const rectWidth2 = 630 * 0 / 100;
const rectHeight2 = 38;
const cornerRadius2 = 37;

ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineWidth = cornerRadius;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF1700';
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';

ctx.strokeRect(rectX2 + (cornerRadius2 / 2), rectY2 + (cornerRadius2 / 2), rectWidth2 - cornerRadius2, rectHeight2 - cornerRadius2);
ctx.fillRect(rectX2 + (cornerRadius2 / 2), rectY2 + (cornerRadius2 / 2), rectWidth2 - cornerRadius2, rectHeight2 - cornerRadius2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="progressBar" width="750" height="120">
</canvas>
```

CODE:

Comment: You need to do the math to make your stroke thinner if the line width is less than the stroke diameter. If it is, then the rect width should be zero and the stroke width should be less. Also, are you sure you don't want to do this with CSS instead?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned this is for a Discord bot, I only use that code snippet so viewers could visualize the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you implement it will have always some of 'matter' when you are at `0%`. If you want have nothing when it's `0%` and that it remains consistent when percentage grow, you don't want use `ctx.lineJoin = "round"`

As a workaround, you might draw the rounded corner instead by using the method [arc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc).

On `arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle)`, we know `x = r`, `y = r` and `radius = r`

[image: calcul of the angle to draw]

We only need some geometry calcul to get the needed values `startAngle` (α) and `endAngle` (α+Δ).

With the trigonometric function [cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions), we have `Math.cos(θ) = (r - p) / r` ⇒ `θ = Math.acos((r - p) / r)`.

We have and  `α = Math.PI - θ`  and we know  `Δ = 2 * θ` ⇒ `(α+Δ) = Math.PI + θ`

So finally:

- `startAngle α = Math.PI - Math.acos((r - p) / r)`
- `endAngle (α+Δ) = Math.PI + Math.acos((r - p) / r)`

In our case, `r = h /2` so when `p < r` ⇔ `p < h / 2`, that gives us:

```
ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - 2 * p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - 2 * p) / h))
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
ctx.fill();
```

```js
const canvas = $("#progressBar");
const ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

const h = 100;
const p = 30;

/* To visalize ------------------------------------------------------*/
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI);
ctx.lineTo(500, 0);
ctx.arc((h / 2) + 500, h / 2, h / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI,Math.PI / 2);
ctx.lineTo(h / 2, h);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - 2 * p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - 2 * p) / h));
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="progressBar" width="750" height="120">
</canvas>
```

Now if we want rather this look (red part, we want to get ride of the grey part). The methode consist to do the same but for half of the progression and then to repeat the same figure in symmetry (hatched area).

[image]

To draw the symetric shape we will use `ctx.scale(-1, 1)` and with the `save()` `restore()` methods. The x position for the center of the 2nd arc will be `- (r - p)` ⇔ `-((h / 2) - p)` and like we will work in horizontal symmetry, it will be finally `(h / 2) - p`

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(-1, 1);
ctx.arc((h / 2) - p, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
ctx.restore();
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
ctx.fill();
```

```js
const canvas = $("#progressBar");
const ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

const h = 100;
const p = 25;

/* To visalize ------------------------------------------------------*/
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI);
ctx.lineTo(500, 0);
ctx.arc((h / 2) + 500, h / 2, h / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI,Math.PI / 2);
ctx.lineTo(h / 2, h);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
ctx.save();
ctx.scale(-1, 1);
ctx.arc((h / 2) - p, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
ctx.restore();
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="progressBar" width="750" height="120">
</canvas>
```

This will be true till `p <= h` after we need to change our code take in account the rectangular part. We will use a if...else to do that.

```
if(p <= h){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(-1, 1);
  ctx.arc((h / 2) - p, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
  ctx.fill();
} else {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI);
  ctx.lineTo(p - 2 * h, 0);
  ctx.arc(p - (h / 2), h / 2, h / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI,Math.PI / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(h / 2, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```js
const canvas = $("#progressBar");
const ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

const h = 100;
const p = 350;

/* To visalize ------------------------------------------------------*/
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI);
ctx.lineTo(500, 0);
ctx.arc((h / 2) + 500, h / 2, h / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI,Math.PI / 2);
ctx.lineTo(h / 2, h);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if(p <= h){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(-1, 1);
  ctx.arc((h / 2) - p, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((h - p) / h), Math.PI + Math.acos((h - p) / h));
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
  ctx.fill();
} else {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(h / 2, h / 2, h / 2, Math.PI / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI);
  ctx.lineTo(p - 2 * h, 0);
  ctx.arc(p - (h / 2), h / 2, h / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI,Math.PI / 2);
  ctx.lineTo(h / 2, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF1700';
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="progressBar" width="750" height="120">
</canvas>
```

Now, we are all good to wrap this up:

```js
const canvas = $("#progressBar");
const ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
const canvasWidth = ctx.canvas.width;
const canvasHeight = ctx.canvas.height;

class progressBar {

  constructor(dimension, color, percentage){
    ({x: this.x, y: this.y, width: this.w, height: this.h} = dimension);
    this.color = color;
    this.percentage = percentage / 100;
    this.p;
  }
  
  static clear(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);  
  }
  
  draw(){
    // Visualize -------
    this.visualize();
    // -----------------
    this.p = this.percentage * this.w;
    if(this.p <= this.h){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.h / 2 + this.x, this.h / 2 + this.y, this.h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((this.h - this.p) / this.h), Math.PI + Math.acos((this.h - this.p) / this.h));
      ctx.save();
      ctx.scale(-1, 1);
      ctx.arc((this.h / 2) - this.p - this.x, this.h / 2 + this.y, this.h / 2, Math.PI - Math.acos((this.h - this.p) / this.h), Math.PI + Math.acos((this.h - this.p) / this.h));
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.closePath();
    } else {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.h / 2 + this.x, this.h / 2 + this.y, this.h / 2, Math.PI / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI);
      ctx.lineTo(this.p - this.h + this.x, 0 + this.y);
      ctx.arc(this.p - (this.h / 2) + this.x, this.h / 2 + this.y, this.h / 2, 3 / 2 * Math.PI, Math.PI / 2);
      ctx.lineTo(this.h / 2 + this.x, this.h + this.y);
      ctx.closePath();
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
  
  visualize(){
    if (wholeprogressbar.checked === true){
      this.showWholeProgressBar();
    }
  }

  showWholeProgressBar(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.h / 2 + this.x, this.h / 2 + this.y, this.h / 2, Math.PI / 2, 3 / 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineTo(this.w - this.h + this.x, 0 + this.y);
    ctx.arc(this.w - this.h / 2 + this.x, this.h / 2 + this.y, this.h / 2, 3 / 2 *Math.PI, Math.PI / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(this.h / 2 + this.x, this.h + this.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  
  get PPercentage(){
    return this.percentage * 100;
  }
  
  set PPercentage(x){
    this.percentage = x / 100;
  }
  
}

// We create new progress bars

progressbar2 = new progressBar({x: 10, y: 10, width: 400, height: 35}, "#FF1700", 50);
// progressbar2.draw(); ---> No need coz we draw them later

progressbar = new progressBar({x: 10, y: 60, width: 400, height: 35}, "#FF1700", 0);
// progressbar.draw(); ---> No need coz we draw them later

// For showing the current percentage (just for example)
setInterval(function() {
 let currentPercentage = progressbar.PPercentage;
    document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = `${Math.round(currentPercentage)} %`;
}, 20);

// We draw the progress-bars (just for example, one fix at 50% and one moving on a range from 0 to 100 %)

let i=0;
setInterval(function() {
  const start = 0;
  const end = 100;
  const step = 0.3;  
  progressbar.PPercentage = i * step;
  progressBar.clear();
  progressbar.draw();
  progressbar2.draw();
  i++;
  if(progressbar.PPercentage > end){
    i = start;
  }
}, 20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="progressBar" width="420" height="100"></canvas>

<div>
    <p> Progression at <span id="percentage"></span></p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="wholeprogressbar" name="wholeprogressbar" onclick="progressbar.draw()">
    <label for="wholeprogressbar">Visualize all the progress bar (100%)</label>
</div>
```

### EDIT :

To create a progress bar, you just have to create a new instance

```
progressbar = new progressBar({x: PositionXinTheCanvas, y: PositionYinTheCanvas, width: WidthOfTheProgressBar, height: HeightOfTheProgressBar}, "ColorOfTheProgressBar", CurrentProgression);
```

..and then draw it

```
progressbar.draw();
```

If you need to clear the canvas, call the `clear()` method. You will need it if you want animate the progress bar. As it's a static method, you need to call it on the class `progressBar` :

```
progressBar.clear();
```

Comment: I am not even going to pretend I understood any of this. Been studying it for over an hour and it still amazes me how thought out and impressive it is. Bravo. Although I am having a little trouble on setting the x and y position, that is down to me being taken aback by this code. I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction. Honestly, well done, if there was an award I could give, I would.

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok My bad, I forgot to put these in account, I corriged & edited the code now

Comment: @RagnarLothbrok I added a "How to use" at the end of the answer, hope it will help to clarify

Answer (score 1):

I started fixing your code, and ended up rewriting it. Here's some important things about how to approach this better.

1. You should really make a function for drawing a line at a specific position and length. Then you have a space to do all the math you need cleanly for a single line at a time.

```
function drawLine(x, y, length) { /* ... */ }
```

2. If you want your line to be 40 pixels long, but corner radius is 40, then then you want to stroke a single point of zero length and width, with a radius of 20, so that the overall width is 40 and the circle is smaller.

```
  // Get length of line that will be stroked
  let innerLength = length - cornerRadius * 2

  // If the line would have a length less than zero, set the length to zero.
  if (innerLength < 0) innerLength = 0

  // If the innerLength is less than the corner diameter, reduce the corner radius to fit.
  let actualCornerRadius = cornerRadius
  if (length < cornerRadius * 2) {
    actualCornerRadius = length / 2
  }
```

3. Since you are drawing a stroked line, and not a rectangle, it simplifies some math to be able to just draw a line from the start point to the end point.

```
  // Find the left and right endpoints of the inner line.
  const leftX = x + actualCornerRadius
  const rightX = leftX + innerLength

  // Draw the path and then stroke it.
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(leftX, y)
  ctx.lineTo(rightX, y)
  ctx.stroke()
```

4. Lastly, to put a rounded stroke on an open path stroke, you just need to set the `lineCap` property of the context to `'round'`.

```
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
```

[Click here for a working demo](https://codepen.io/Squeegy/pen/QWbBNNz?editors=0011).

Comment: This is a much better way to do it! Thank you, however, the issue is still present. I need the X position to be constant, this bar goes inside of a box and the same issue of it leaving the box is still present see: https://imgur.com/a/ZiGtlmH

Comment: Well, change the math so it works that way. Hint: play with the math that sets the `leftX` variable.

Comment: That doesn't solve anything about the issue (which reworded is "how to make lineCap round end at defined coords")